Closable operator lemma proof
A linear operator A
is closable if and only if for every sequence xn
in H
such that xn→0
and Axn→y
for some y∈H
, it follows that y=0

Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? Also, you should try to write maths using MathJax, which is pretty much similar to LaTeX if you're familiar with that. There are MathJax tutorials on the Meta side of this site.
